# Why this SQL query return false when i try to bind values (even prepare statement)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I tried to solve it with PDO and mysqli prepared statements but it still return false. So something is probably wrong with sql statement only, but i don't know what exacly.

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bricks WHERE "text" LIKE CONCAT("%", :phrase, "%") AND tags LIKE CONCAT("%", :tag, "%") ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT {$start},{$pagesOnSite}');
$query->bindValue(':phrase', $phrase, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':tag', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

I also tried it this way:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM bricks WHERE "text" LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%") AND tags LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%") ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT {$start},{$pagesOnSite}';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $phrase, $tag);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: why are you using concat on the wildcards?

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around `text` in your query? Now it is the string `text`, not a column name.

Comment: I thought i have to use concat because i can't use "%?%"

Comment: i changed it now, its text

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM bricks WHERE text LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%") AND tags LIKE CONCAT("%", ?, "%") ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT 0,12

Comment: `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` i thought it doesn't matter which opening and closing quotes i use

Comment: @Steve143 sorry I did not look at the error. I think it is actually a warning and you could simply ignore it or create the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind some text literal surrounded by wildcards, then you should build that entire string value in your PHP code.  Then, bind it to your statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bricks ";
$sql .= "WHERE text LIKE :phrase AND tags LIKE :tag ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY hearts DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$pagesOnSite}";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':phrase', '%'.$phrase.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':tag', '%'.$tag.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works great. Can you show me how to do it with mysqli prepared statements (second way i tried, but failed)?

Comment: Will it be $stmt->bind_param("ss", "%".$phrase."%", "%".$tag."%"); ?

Comment: When i try this in stmt way i got: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: @Steve143 You should ask a new question if you need help with a different API.  I have answered your original question.

Comment: @Steve143 This is something you should handle in your PHP logic.  Why on Earth would you be binding a literal `%` to your statement?

Comment: You need to escape with backslash `WHERE col LIKE '%100\%%'` ... by the way, this has _nothing_ to do with your original question, hence again I have flagged your comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180735/discussion-between-steve143-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: No, I _won't_ chat with you.  Stack Overflow is not some tawdry fast food restaurant where you keep coming back for free refills.  Your question was answered, and if you have other issues, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I thought that I can avoid filtering user input data by prepared statements